# Does the VFW (Video For Windows) API support Alpha Channel Transparency?

Tags: mfc, alpha, visual-c++-6, vfw, color-channel

Does the VFW (Video For Windows) API support Alpha Channel Transparency? I want to be able to export video with Alpha channel information. How can I do this in VC6?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it does; just set the pixel format to RGB32, which should give you an alpha channel to use.

Of course, finding a video compression format that fits all your needs and supports alpha channel is another problem.